# Null Pointer exception while running Jmeter test in Java

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

Following is my simple code to run jmeter test plan in Java8.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;


public class JmxSuite {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\PLACES\\apache-jmeter-2.11");



        HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setDomain("exapmle.com");
        httpSampler.setPort(80);
        httpSampler.setPath("/");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");


        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.initialize();


        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);

        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("RKSV Jmeter Testing");

        testPlanTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
        testPlanTree.add("loopController", loopController);
        testPlanTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
        testPlanTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);

        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }
}
```

But I am keep getting the following error while running it.

```
INFO    2016-04-07 15:40:44.060 [jmeter.e] (): Listeners will be started after enabling running version
INFO    2016-04-07 15:40:44.079 [jmeter.e] (): To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false
INFO    2016-04-07 15:40:44.108 [jmeter.p] (): No response parsers defined: text/html only will be scanned for embedded resources
INFO    2016-04-07 15:40:44.115 [jmeter.p] (): Maximum connection retries = 10
INFO    2016-04-07 15:40:44.121 [jmeter.e] (): Running the test!
INFO    2016-04-07 15:40:44.141 [jmeter.s] (): List of sample_variables: []
INFO    2016-04-07 15:40:44.141 [jmeter.s] (): List of sample_variables: []
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.setProperty(JMeterUtils.java:885)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.startTest(JMeterContextService.java:92)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:313)
    at JmxSuite.main(JmxSuite.java:48)
```

And following is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Places</groupId>
  <artifactId>Places</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

What could be the possible reason for it?
I have used code from 4th topic from this [5 ways to run jmeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing few lines from the article, double check your code, to wit:

```
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:\\PLACES\\apache-jmeter-2.11\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
JMeterUtils.initLogging();
JMeterUtils.initLocale();
```

Also there is an example project [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/) which can be used as a reference or skeleton.

Also consider using latest version of JMeter, for the moment it's [Apache JMeter 2.13](https://blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-know-about-jmeter-213)

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because the internal Properties-object of JMeterUtils is null at this point. Add the following line to your code to initalize this object:

```
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
```

EDIT: Instead of doing it all manually you should call

```
JMeterUtils.initializeProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
```

which is the correct way and does all the initalizing of logging and locale internally.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Never realized those props are so important.